# VSTO connecting with 32-bit ODBC connection

Tags: visual-studio, odbc, vsto, outlook-addin, 32bit-64bit

I am deploying a outlook add-in. All users have a 64-bit windows and a 32-bit ODBC connection. But on the office side some have 32 bit office other have 64 bit.

Usually I would Target "Any CPU" and tick the Prefer 32-bit for the app to use the 32-bit ODBC connection and everything runs perfectly.

But the "Prefer 32-bit" is greyed out in visual-studio for VSTO add-ins.

On my pc:
Windows 64-bit / office 32-bit / odbc 32-bit only

everythin works perfectly.

Other user :
Windows 64-bit / office 64-bit / odbc 32-bit only

I get the error: Error IM014, message: [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] The specified DSN contains an architecture mismatch between the Driver and Application

I tried targeting : x86 but then it can't even install on the 64-bit office, I get error message : Not loaded. A runtime error occurred during the loading of the COM add-in

Is there a way in code for odbc to use 32-bit in a 64-bit compiled software?

Answer (score 0):

VSTO addins are always loaded in-proc by Outlook, hence the always run with the bitness of the parent process - Outlook.